# Outlook add-in: get attachments and calculate total size from new email

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-restapi

Im working with outlook add-in. I have a requirement that I have to throw the error if attachment's `total size > 10MB`.

Im using following to save the new email as draft

```
const officeIns = this.getOfficeIns();
officeIns.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync((result) => {
   cb(result.value);
});
```

And I have following code to get email attachments

`` // Inside callback function to officeIns.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${olUserTokenObj['token']}`);
const emailMessageId =  officeIns.context.mailbox.convertToRestId(messageId, officeIns.MailboxEnums.RestVersion.v2_0);
console.log('rest id', emailMessageId);
const options = { headers: headers, withCredentials: false };
let graphApiUrl = `https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages`;
graphApiUrl = `${graphApiUrl}/${emailMessageId}/attachments?$select=Size,Name&_=${Date.now()}`;
const data = await this.httpClient.get(graphApiUrl, options).toPromise();
// ... calculating total size from `data.value` ``

and if there is an error on getting attachments, im retrying get attachments with 10sec delay for 5 times

However the attachments is getting saved in sometime only and it is not saving mostly. I see this problem more in outlook client's add-in.

It seems that `saveAsync` is not saving attachments. Can any one help me on this problem

**Questions:**

1. Can I use saveAsync function to save attachments?
2. Do we have any office.js event which triggers on after save all attachments to the server?
3. Is there any other way to solve this problem?

I have read through this document and I don't find relevant information.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.7/office.context.mailbox.item#saveasyncoptions-callback

Answer (score 1):

You might have a problem with saveAsync and desktop client cached mode. This problem was already noticed by others and here is explanation in one of the [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46671562/how-can-we-force-a-mailbox-item-to-be-persisted-to-ews?rq=1) questions along with some possible mitigation of the problem. There is also a request for enhancement/feature from the [community](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/34593391-immediate-synced-to-the-server-saveasync-to-get) that you can upvote and hope it gets done in near future.

Comment: This answer is most likely what is happening. How are the attachments added in your scenario (that was a big unclear). if you are adding them via Graph/EWS, then they will not show up in the client. If they are added on the client (either through the UI/User or through the addFileAttachmentAsync api), then they should be saved and uploaded up to the server at some point. However, due to cache mode it may take some time for the client/server to sync.